# Pass 'host parameter' to ServerSocket in java

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, http-proxy

I am currently working under proxy server (the core was taken from here https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9781565923713/blob/master/SimpleProxyServer.java)

But, this example uses launch parameters, when I want to pass host directly from the client.

Client is a HTTP connection like that

```
final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://www.google.com")
                    .openConnection(
                            new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 7901)));
conn.connect();
System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
```

My initial idea was to read client's request, store it as String (or byty[]), fetch header's "Host:" parameter and pass it to server.

However, SimpleProxyServer.java uses `while((bytes_read = from_client.read(request)) != -1)` in the Thread that sends data to server, and code hangs on that moment if I read InputSream to get host before this `t` thread was started.

I am talking about something like this

```
InputStreamReader from_client_reader = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(from_client_reader);
        String line = reader.readLine();

        while (!line.isEmpty()) {
            line = reader.readLine();
            if (line.contains("Host: ")) {
                host = line.substring(line.indexOf("Host: ") + 6,
                        line.length()).trim().replace("www.", "");
            }
        }
```

Right before creating of the connection `try { server = new Socket(host, remoteport); }`

The question is: "Is there other ways on how to pass parameters to Socket or how to create Proxy server that launches Socket using request parameters from the client?"

Answer (score 0):

Well, if someone ever wonders, I decided to create another small Socket server that listens for commands from client, and launches process (`java -jar ProxyServer.jar <...>`) through Runtime. Also, kills this process if necessary.

Basically, client has to send two requests: one to setup Proxy server, another to connect to the proxy server.

I am sure there is a better solution for this, however, this one suits me.